# Translate polygon location

Tags: java, polygon, mousemove, polygons

I want to write a program which allows me to drag a polygon according to my mouse, and it's initial mousePressed location. The code works, but the problem is that it's not sensitive at all, and every little mouse movement gives much bigger translation. Is there any way to improve it? Here is the code:

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

    //Get mousePressed coordinates
    xMousePressed = e.getX();
    yMousePressed = e.getY();
}
@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

    //Drag polygon only if mouse was pressed in the center of the screen
    if (270 < xMousePressed && xMousePressed < 520 
     && 205 < yMousePressed && yMousePressed < 390){

        //Create new mouse location, relative to the last one.
        int xTemp = (int) ((e.getX() - xMousePressed));
        int yTemp = (int) ((e.getY() - yMousePressed));

        //Get list of all the polygons on screen.
        java.util.List<Polygon> tempList = scene.getPolygons();

        //For each point of each polygon
        for(Polygon p: tempList){               
            for(int i = 0; i < p.npoints; i++){
                //Move
                p.xpoints[i] += xTemp;
                p.ypoints[i] += yTemp;                  
            }               
        }

        //Update the mouse position for next movement
        yMousePressed = e.getX();
        yMousePressed = e.getY();

        //Draw the changes on screen.
        this.repaint();
    }       
}
```

Comment: You could use the 2D shapes API, which can translate the shape directly, or you could translate the graphics context

Comment: "much bigger translation"  You mean that if you press and move 10 pixels to the right the polygon moves more than 10 pixels?

Comment: I mean that the movement of the polygon seems to be disproportional to the mouse movement.